# trying to clone my git repository to my local machine

Tags: linux, github

Noob here, trying to clone my git repository to my local machine. When I run the command it asks me for my password but it does not recognize it.
When I click out of the password prompt it gives me this message in the terminal.

"Cloning into 'git_test'... sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED "/home/name/.ssh/id_ed" from agent: agent refused operation git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."

Comment: github recently changed stuff to be "more secure". Now you have to find their web page where you can generate yourself some access key. Of course, you do not stand a chance to memorize it so you place it into a file on your computer for convenient copy and pasting and with that done, you are less secure, I guess :)

Comment: Does this have to do with my ssh key? and is this access key specific to my computer? usually, when I am working on the command line and it prompts my password it's the password I log into my computer with.

Comment: this migfht helo you https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey